# How to get Parent SKU of a Child Product in Checkout Page?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8

Can anyone please let me know how to get parent sku of a child product in a checkout page. I'm using `$session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');` object in my checkout page.

Comment: Have you got the child whose parent you are after?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you want to get the parent sku for all your simple product

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
foreach($session->getQuote()->getAllItems() as $item) {
    if($item->getTypeId() == "simple" && $item->getParentItemId()){        
        $parent = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getParentItemId()); 
        $parent->getSku();

        //or as @Richard mention you could just do
        $item->getParentItem()->getProduct()->getSku()
    }
}
```

*NOTE : A simple item can have multiple parent ids*

Also take a look at [Get parent SKU (configurable or bundle) from child SKU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480126/get-parent-sku-configurable-or-bundle-from-child-sku)

Update

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
foreach($session->getQuote()->getAllItems() as $item) {
    if($parent = $item->getParentItem()){  
        $parent->getProduct()->getSku()
        //echo $parent->getSku()
    }
 }
```

Comment: getAllVisibleItems explicitly excludes child items:
    public function getAllVisibleItems()
        {
        $items = array();
        foreach ($this->getItemsCollection() as $item) {
            if (!$item->isDeleted() && !$item->getParentItemId()) {
                $items[] =  $item;
            }
        }
        return $items;
    }

Comment: @Richard ... Thanks, I just updated it to use `getAllItems()` instead

Comment: OK, I just deleted my own answer because it was wrong (the sku of the parent Item is the sku of the Product in the child Item, not the parent Product), but: you're getting the parentITEMid and then loading the product model by that id, that should probably be $item->getParentItem()->getProduct()->getSku(). (getProduct()) will load it for you

Comment: It will load it for you, but sometime it doesn't load the full product object just the flat table fields. But in this case sku will always be present

Comment: I sort of agree with you, I have hit exactly that issue with Sales/Order before, in this instance though, it wouldn't matter if the products were loaded from the flat tables, they'd still have their skus

Comment: Needs getProduct()-> before getSku(), the quote table stores the child Product sku against the child and parent Item (Sorry)

Comment: Take a look at app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item/Abstract.php. getParentItem() return Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item which contain the item sku (but your right this sku depend on your config product sku setting)

Comment: >> NOTE : A simple item can have multiple parent ids ..... .but the OP question is different maybe. `How can you get the parent product in checkout` meaning if we look at the quote for a configurable product there are 2 lines in de quote table: the child and the related parent ... how can we find the related specific parent for the child product in the current quote (only) https://pasteboard.co/HCCO65j.png